# How to add the numbers present in a string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, casting

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 char *a="12345";   //Add number of that string
}
```

---

How can i add number of that string

**example :**

```
sum=1+2+3+4+5

sum=15
```

How can i do that?

Comment: `1+2+3+4+5` is `15` not `14` , for starters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sum = 0;
char *a = "12345";

while (*a) {
   sum += *a - '0';
   a++;
}

printf("sum=%d\n", sum);
```

Comment: As for beginner , you should provide some explanation or comments for OP to understand it :-)

Comment: @ameyCU some one (which i thanks by the way) changed the instructions to this `sum += *a++ - '0';` while it is elegant, it is not clear for a beginner.

Comment: @milevyo  I was referring for all over code . But yeah ,that could have been confusing .

Comment: @milevyo I don't agree that the edit was elegant, it made the code much harder to read and also dangerous, since mixing the `++` operator with other operators is bad practice. Your code with `a++` on a separate line is much better and safer, and that has nothing to do with it being more beginner-friendly. Furthermore, edits should not change coding style of posts. It was a bad edit, simple as that. I believe you always have the option to reject edits of your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to provide a pretty **basic solution** to this question..

1)convert the given string to integer and store it's value into a variable, lets say `n` using the function `atoi()` function. know more about it by clicking [THIS!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm). and by the way **it's pretty easy to understand, it just changes the string mentioned inside brackets to integer.**

2)and then using a `for loop` calculate the sum.

Here I have provided my solution to your problem, I don't think you'll have any problems in tracing out the code. If any help is required, feel free to comment :)

Here's my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,sum=0; //i is loop parameter and sum is used to store the sum of numbers
    char *a="12345";
    n=atoi(a);  //atoi(string) function is used to change a string into integer 
    printf("%d",n);

    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++) //loop to calculate the sum
    {
        sum=sum+(n%10);
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("\n\nsum = %d\n\n",sum);
}
```

Hope it's helpful.